# does abstract class in C++ mean abstraction?

Tags: c++

Lot of tutorials list abstraction as one of 4 basic principles in C++ (remaining 3 as encapsulation, inheritance and polymorphism). I tried to understand the concept of abstraction. Lot of online tutorials say that abstraction is a concept which hides the implementation details and provides only the interface. I didn't clearly understand this point. I didn't understand what we are hiding. Is this talking about hiding the internal structures that the function uses? if that is the case, even normal C function also will do this. When I talked with one of my colleague about this, he told abstract class is the best example of abstraction. But I didn't understand this also. Because when we have pure virtual function, we can't create an instance of the class and the pure virtual function mostly doesn't have definition. So there is no concept of hiding in this case. Can any one please explain abstraction in C++ with example?

Comment: Not sure I'm happy with having those as _the 4 basic principles of C++_. They can be used to describe some foundations of object-oriented programming I guess, but even for that there seems to be too much overlap for my tastes to make for a solid basis. For describing the C++ language they seem even less fit to me, in particular if you don't approach the language from an object-oriented angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstraction is something very natural in every day life, it is very common to talk about something without getting into many details of the thing. You can use your car without thinking/knowing  about mechanics, fluid mechanics, chemistry, engineering, etc. Abstraction in computer engineering is exactly the same thing (in general).

Yes a simple function provides an abstraction. But functions are just small parts of a software, and they are sometimes built by factoring the code (a good idea but that do not always lead to a good abstraction). An abstraction should have a clear semantic meaning not tricky.

OOP is a paradigm in witch you can built new types and let you forget about the details of them. As in an course about algorithm where one can tell you how quicksort works but never speak about the real nature of the elements they are sorting (it is certainly not an interesting point in sorting). What is interesting about object (as with your car) is the way one can manipulate an object not how the behavior is realized. I want to turn to the left by rotating the steering to the left, I don't want to know that really happens behind the scene when I do this. When I leave my car to the repair man, I let him do anything he wants on my car provided that it works as usual (he can change anything he wants behind the scene). As a user I just want to focus on the manual not the internals. So you need to make a difference in between the **interface** of an ideal object (the manual) and the **realization** of a concrete object (the internals schemas). This is what every OOP language let you write (in different ways of course you have a variety of possibilities to realize all of this).

So you want to talk about points on the plane somewhere in your code? Let's talk about the manual (a short one for the sake on simplicity). A Point is an object from which you can get its cartesian coordinates or its polar ones, right? Then its abstract, whatever a Point is obtain/realized in the software you want to be able to do this with it. So it is an abstraction:

```
class Point {
  public:
    virtual double getX() = 0;
    virtual double getY() = 0;
    virtual double getAngle() = 0;
    virtual double getLength() = 0;
}
```

This is a manual, with this you can use a point (provided you have one), then you can write a valid compilable code:

```
void f(Point *p) {
    cout << p->getX() << "," << p->getY() << endl;
}
```

Here you need to be careful, either pass a pointer or a reference. You pass an object as an abstraction, then something should happen to retrieve the realization, in C++ this necessitate reference or pointer. Note that this function does not receive a Point (a Point is an abstraction something that doesn't exists), but can receive any kind of realization of a Point (this makes a big difference). Note: that this code is compilable and remains valid while you call it with a realization of the abstraction (this can be valid for a very very long time! Code reusability, you know?)

Ok now somewhere you can realize the abstraction:

```
class PolarPoint : public Point {
  private:
    double angle, length;
  public:
    PolarPoint(double a,double l) : angle(a), length(l) {}
    virtual double getX() { return length*cos(angle); }
    virtual double getY() { return length*sin(angle); }
    virtual double getLength() { return length; }
    virtual double getAngle() { return angle; }
}
```

Somewhere you instantiate it (create an object of this concrete model and then use it (then forget about all of its specificity) :

```
...
Point *p = new PolarPoint(3.14/4,10.0);
f( p );
....
```

Remind that `f` has been compiled even a long time ago, but works with this new realization now! An abstraction is a kind of contract.

You can also realize in another way:

```
class CartesianPoint : public Point {
  private:
    double x, y;
  public:
    CartesianPoint(double x,double y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    virtual double getX() { return x; }
    virtual double getY() { return y; }
    virtual double getLength() { return /* the calculus from x/y*/; }
    virtual double getAngle() { return /* the calculus from x/y */; }
}

...
Point *p2 = new CartesianPoint(3.14/6,20.56);
f( p );
...
```

In this example I also used information hiding, concept related to abstraction (at least useful with abstraction). private/public is related to information hiding, which lets you enforce the hiding, meaning that the user of a class can't access (at least too easily) the details, not only he is discouraged from look at them but he can't manipulate them. Again, with your car, it is not easy to change a piston, not only because it is an inner part of the engine but also because the constructor provide many ways to hide this from you : no instruction manual to do so, special tools difficult to obtain, etc. You may know that your car has a carburetor, but you may be unable to touch it.

Beware that abstraction does not mean hiding, but just let you forget about the details if you don't want to (and in general you don't want to). Abstraction is a good way to obtain low coupling of software components.

Answer (score 2):

You should distinguish between a language construct as abstract classes and a generic concept as abstraction.

Although abstract classes may be a useful tool in creating abstractions it's not a necessary tool, neither is using that tool a guarantee that you would get a (good) abstraction.

For example there are abstractions all over the place in the C++ standard so one should not require to come up with another example.

Take for example the STL. There are a number of containers of different kind, but for example there are sequences which all conform to a common set of functions defined on them, in addition there are guaranteed complexities for different operations depending on which one you select. The abstraction here is that these are sequential containers that you can use to store data in. Although they don't use virtual functions, the implementation varies from implementation to implementation (or at least could vary), but if you use it according to the specification the actual implementation would not matter to the programmer (and most often the programmer does not dig into the actual implementation).

Another abstraction in the specification is the language itself, the execution environment specified therein and the translation process. These parts are not specified in terms of how they are implemented, but according to the expected behavior. For example normally an implementation would implement local variables by putting them on the processor stack, but that is an implementation detail that the C++ specification leaves out. The specification puts up a number of assumptions about the behavior of the execution. And you construct your program using these assumptions instead of assuming that the implementation would need to be done in a specific concrete way.

Answer (score 1):

No, abstraction does not mean you must hide the internal structures.

*CPP Primer Plus, page 507* give you an explain and also the example.

> Life is full of complexities, and one way we cope with complexity is to frame simplifying
>   abstractions.You are a collection of more than an octillion atoms. Some students of the
>   mind would say that your mind is a collection of several semiautonomous agents. But it’s
>   much simpler to think of yourself as a single entity. In computing, abstraction is the crucial
>   step of representing information in terms of its interface with the user.That is, you
>   abstract the essential operational features of a problem and express a solution in those
>   terms. In the softball statistics example, the interface describes how the user initializes,
>   updates, and displays the data. From abstraction, it is a short step to the user-defined type,
>   which in C++ is a class design that implements the abstract interface.

Answer (score 1):

> Lot of tutorials list abstraction as one of 4 basic principles in C++ (remaining 3 as encapsulation, inheritance and polymorphism).

That list seems to describe ***Object Orientation***, in any language.  C++ has many "basic principles" depending on your perspective, and there's no agreed upon list.

> I tried to understand the concept of abstraction. Lot of online tutorials say that abstraction is a concept which hides the implementation details and provides only the interface. I didn't clearly understand this point. I didn't understand what we are hiding. Is this talking about hiding the internal structures that the function uses? if that is the case, even normal C function also will do this.

Let's look at an example.  Let's imagine a program handles a series of numeric inputs, and at a high - "abstract" - level, it wants to collect some statistics about those numbers.  We might write:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Stats, typename T>
bool process_input(std::istream& in, Stats& stats)
{
    T v;
    while (in >> std::skipws && !in.eof() && in >> v)
        stats(v);
    return in;  // true if no errors
}
```

In the above code, we "call" `stats` with each value `v` that we read from the input.  But, we have no idea what `stats` does with the values: does it save them all, calculate min, max, a total, stdddev, the third percentile?  Someone else can care because we've written our input logic above to ***abstract*** away those questions: the caller can provide a suitable `stats` object that does whatever's necessary (even nothing), as long as it's valid to "call" it with a value of type `T` using the `stats(v)` notation.  Similarly, we didn't make a decision about what types of data the input would contain: `T` could be `double`, or `std::string`, or `int` or some yet-to-be-written class, and yet our algorithm would work for any of those because it abstracts the input logic.

> Say we want a `Stats` object that can find the minimum and maximum of a set of values.  In C++, I could write:

```
template <typename T>
class Stats
{
  public:
    Stats() : num_samples_(0) { }

    void operator()(T t)
    {
        if (++num_samples_ == 1)
            minimum_ = maximum_ = t;
        else if (t < minimum_)
            minimum_ = t;
        else if (t > maximum_)
            maximum_ = t;
    }
    T minimum() const { return minimum_; }
    T maximum() const { return maximum_; }
    size_t num_samples() const { return num_samples_; }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Stats& s)
    {
        os << "{ #" << s.num_samples_;
        if (s.num_samples_)
            os << ", min " << minimum_ << ", max " << maximum_;
        return os << " }";
    }
  private:
    size_t num_samples_;
    T minimum_, maximum_;
};
```

This is just one possible implementation of an object that can be passed to `process_input` above.  It is the `void operator()(T t)` function that satisfies the interface expectations of `process_input`.  Any other function that handles a series of values could pass them to a `Stat` object, and they could even stream out the collected stats...

```
std::cout << stats << '\n';
```

...without ever understanding which statistics were calculated/collected.  Again, that's abstraction: you can say ***what*** is to be done at a very high level, without knowing the lower-level details, let alone ***how*** it will be done.

> When I talked with one of my colleague about this, he told abstract class is the best example of abstraction. But I didn't understand this also. Because when we have pure virtual function, we can't create an instance of the class and the pure virtual function mostly doesn't have definition. So there is no concept of hiding in this case. Can any one please explain abstraction in C++ with example?

What you're hiding with abstraction is how things get done - that's expressed in the definitions, so an abstract class does at least have that small amount of abstraction.  Still, let's contrast the above example that had a reasonable level of abstraction from code that lacks abstraction, despite the use of an abstract class:

```
class Abstract_Stats
{
  public:
    virtual double get_minimum() const = 0;
    virtual void set_minimum(double m) = 0;
    virtual double get_maximum() const = 0;
    virtual void set_maximum(double m) = 0;
  private:
    double minimum_, maximum_;
};
```

With such a stupid abstract class, our `process_input` function would need to be rewritten thus:

```
bool process_input(std::istream& in, Abstract_Stats& stats)
{
    int v;
    size_t n = 0;
    while (in >> std::skipws && !in.eof() && in >> v)
        if (++n == 1) { stats.set_minimum(v); stats.set_maximum(v); }
        else if (v < stats.get_minimum()) stats.set_minimum(v);
        else if (v > stats.get_maximum()) stats.set_maximum(v);
    return in;  // true if no errors
}
```

Suddenly, our `Abstract_Stats` class with it's less abstract interface has forced us to mix specifics of statistics gathering functionality into the input logic.

So, abstraction is less about whether a function is pure virtual, and more about the division of work to make things reusable in different combinations, with each being cleanly testable and understandable independently.

Answer (score 0):

#### Abstraction and abstact classes are not the same.

**Abstraction is simply creating a model of a concept or thing.** However, abstraction in programming usually implies that the model is more simple than what you're abstracting. This goes for mostly all programming languages: most have constructs or ways to model what you want so that it somehow gives a benefit.

Abstracting a traffic flow simulation, for example, as a bunch of unrelated variables is messy. However, if you model each individual vehicle as an ***object***, each object can handle its own internal state and it becomes simpler to deal with the idea of a "Vehicle" object than a bunch of variables that are not related to each other.

**Abstract classes are more like Java's interfaces.** They are meant to serve as a uniform programming "interface" within different internal parts of a program. By confining how objects can interact with other objects, you bring determinism to a program by confining how the program can program. It often leverages a langauge's type system to reduce the amount of unpredictable behavior or unwanted behavior that occurs within parts of a program by forcing it to conform to type constraints.

Some examples of abstraction: lambda calculus, objects, structs, constructors and destructors, polymorphism, etc.